# Ollydbg not showing any code of a windows application

Tags: ollydbg

i want to disassemble a windows application which is written in microsoft visual c++. When i open it in Ollydbg 110 than it is showing that application is running but there is no code shown there.

I don't understand what is the problem with the application.
Can Anybody tell me what is going wrong or am i missing something??

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What application? And have you used ollydbg before?

Comment: yes, i have used it before and it is showing assembly language for all exe files but not for a perticular one which i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to watch Lena's reversing tutorial. It will introduce you to OllyDbg and the basic concepts.

Basically you can attach to a process or start a process from the debugger. By default, when you attach it should break the application and show you the current state of the application. You might want to take a look at the settings and setup when to break. 
[image]

The other possibility might be that you are in a different module (like you are watching a loaded rundll or kernel, instead of your core module of your application). To check this go here:
[image]

A third option could be that the application is using some kind of anti debugging technique.

Did you try the newest version of ollydbg?